# How do I set/return the postcss result to a variable?

Tags: javascript, sass, postcss

I have string of CSS that's rendered from Sass's renderSync function and I would like to run it through postcss-preset-env, but I can't get the CSS to return as string that I can store in a variable which I then want to inject into a pug template so that I can insert the CSS in a  tag; embedded CSS. Is this not possible when using postcss-preset-env? Here is some sample code:

postcss-preset-env@^6.0.7

```
const sass = require('node-sass');
const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');
const postcss = require('postcss');

let sassString = `
    $bgcolor: #000000;
    body { background-color: $bgcolor; }
`;

let css = sass.renderSync({data:sassString}).css.toString();

let process = postcss([postcssPresetEnv()]).process(css).css;

console.log(process);
```

Comment: I've also tried `postcssPresetEnv.process()`